# Error CTJSO1501E from Bluemix SSO Web UI

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

Attempting to set up an instance of the Bluemix SSO service for use in an app.  I created a service instance but when I click on the tile to open it so that I can configure the settings I get:

com.ibm.sec.iam.platform.ui.DashboardException: CTJSO1501E You have arrived at this page without valid parameters. You must visit this page via the Bluemix administration console.

Now, I thought I *was* in the Bluemix administration console. I mean, I'm coming from this page:

```
https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/dashboard/all
```

I tried coming at this from other paths but every time I try to open the service I get this error.

Would appreciate any thoughts on what is wrong here or how I might workaround this failure.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not seeing this problem. Which browser do you use? You can try switching to a different browser, or cleaning current browser cache to see if that helps.

Comment: This does seem to be browser related.  My original attempt was using Safari, so I tried using Chrome, and got no error with Chrome.  Tried again with Safari and it still gives the whacky CTJSO1501E error.  So I guess I'll just use Chrome for now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same when using Safari on Mac. Using Chrome, it goes through.